# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Routine (cdc_endcapture) can not be resolved while initializing IfxCDCEngine builder on Informix Change Stream Client

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, informix

Tried out this code for Informix Change Streams API for Java . from https://informix.hcldoc.com/14.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cdc.doc%2Fids_cdc_streamapi.htm

I Keep on getting this error .Is there any fix for this or solution??

```
16:03:57.054 [main] DEBUG com.informix.stream.cdc.IfxCDCEngine - Closing down CDC engine
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Routine (cdc_opensess) can not be resolved.
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildExceptionWithMessage(IfxErrMsg.java:422)
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildIsamException(IfxErrMsg.java:401)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3022)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3273)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2269)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2194)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executePrepare(IfxSqli.java:1194)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.setupExecutePrepare(IfxPreparedStatement.java:245)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxCallableStatement.<init>(IfxCallableStatement.java:143)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareCall(IfxSqliConnect.java:5924)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareCall(IfxSqliConnect.java:2499)
    at com.informix.stream.cdc.IfxCDCEngine.init(IfxCDCEngine.java:177)
    at com.example.informixchangestream.demo.CDCExDemoApplicationample.main(CDCExDemoApplicationample.java:33)
    Suppressed: com.informix.stream.impl.IfxStreamException: Unable to end cdc capture 
        at com.informix.stream.cdc.IfxCDCEngine.endCapture(IfxCDCEngine.java:295)
        at com.informix.stream.cdc.IfxCDCEngine.unwatchTable(IfxCDCEngine.java:275)
        at com.informix.stream.cdc.IfxCDCEngine.close(IfxCDCEngine.java:343)
        at com.example.informixchangestream.demo.CDCExDemoApplicationample.main(CDCExDemoApplicationample.java:52)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Routine (cdc_endcapture) can not be resolved.
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildExceptionWithMessage(IfxErrMsg.java:422)
        at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.buildIsamException(IfxErrMsg.java:401)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.addException(IfxSqli.java:3022)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveError(IfxSqli.java:3273)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.dispatchMsg(IfxSqli.java:2269)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2194)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executePrepare(IfxSqli.java:1194)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxPreparedStatement.setupExecutePrepare(IfxPreparedStatement.java:245)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxCallableStatement.<init>(IfxCallableStatement.java:143)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareCall(IfxSqliConnect.java:5924)
        at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.prepareCall(IfxSqliConnect.java:2499)
        at com.informix.stream.cdc.IfxCDCEngine.endCapture(IfxCDCEngine.java:282)
        ... 3 more
```

My code looks like this :

```
try (IfxCDCEngine engine = builder.build()) {

            // initialize the engine (creates the connections and begins listening for
            // changes)

            engine.init();
            IfmxStreamRecord record = null;

            // This loop is where you can inject logic that compiles
            // transactions, look for commits, throw away rollbacks
            // The data here is all Java typed, so it can be easily then
            // sent to MQTT, other JDBC drivers, streaming engines, or anything
            // else you can think of.
            while ((record = engine.getRecord()) != null) {
                // Print out the basic record information
                System.out.println("record changed");
                System.out.println(record);

                // If it is an insert/update/delete, print the column data
                if (record.hasOperationData()) {
                    System.out.println("operation data");
                    System.out.println(((IfxCDCOperationRecord) record).getData());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is happens when the CDC routines are not found. Make sure that you first run the CDC setup script with the server to create the `syscdcv1` database.

Then make sure your DataSource connects to the `syscdcv1` database when you try CDC operations. It's not intuitive, but you 'connect' to the `syscdcv1` database, then add `watchers` on databases and tables you are interested in getting the changes for.

Documentation on the CDC setup on the server is here, you need step #2 at least.
https://informix.hcldoc.com/14.10/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cdc.doc%2Fids_cdc_streamapi.htm

A working example can be found here with a README and java code that you can use that might be easier to follow than the pages of the official docs
https://github.com/informix/informix-db-examples/tree/master/streaming/cdc